# Query given list of values equivalent to sql IN

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am stuck trying to figure out how to use the equivalent of "IN" in sql with MongoDB as I am not getting any results.

Here is sample output of the record/document:

```
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("12348749e4b04b2d017ff78e"),
                "account" : "foo",
                "archivedFilteredEvents" : [
                        {
                                "id" : "all_events",
                                "name" : "All Events",
                                "enabled" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "id" : "f123dsad2",
                                "name" : "test1",
                                "enabled" : true
                        }
]
```

Here is the query I need help with:

```
printjson(db.mytestdb_profiles.find({
 "account" : "foo", 
 "archivedFilteredEvents.id" : [ "all_events","f123dsad2"]}
));
```

I am basically looking for the equivalent of:

```
select id, name, enabled
from mytestdb_profiles
where account = 'foo'
and id.archivedFilteredDEvents IN ('all_events', 'f123dsad2');
```

Comment: Here are the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator in your query:

```
db.mytestdb_profiles.find({
 "account" : "foo", 
 "archivedFilteredEvents.id" : { $in: [ "all_events","f123dsad2"] } }
)
```